# How to do a null check inside of an EOD in php

Tags: php

Never really had any experience with php. Wondering how I can do something like this

```
$html = $html . <<<EOD
            <h10>Quick ID:</h10> if (!empty($row->quickid))
```

I only want that row to be inserted if it isn't null. it honestly would be better if i could do something like this.

```
$html = $html . <<<EOD
            (!empty($row->quickid)) <h10>Quick ID:</h10> if $row->quickid
```

Any help is my appreciated

Comment: afaik you can't write php logic inside of a heredoc string

Comment: See heredoc documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc I am afraid you can't.

Comment: Would it be appropriate to do something like this :

 if (!empty($row->quickid)) $html = $html .'<h10>Quick ID:' . $row->quickid . '</h10>  {<br>';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you wan't to use heredoc why not do something like this (assuming it's what you want as the result):

This is a shorthand true false. First you write the condition, then behind the question mark what todo when the statement is true and behind the doubledot what todo when the statement is false.

```
$html .= !empty($row->quickid) ? '<h10>Quick ID:</h10>' : '';
```

Comment: Yes, this is a perfect solution. Like I said, I haven't dealt with much php. Wasn't fully aware this was an option - was just looking at was already there and trying to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: glad to be of assistance ;)